# Code::Blocks 17.12 not compiling

Tags: c++, code-blocks

I am having a problem.
I am running Ubuntu 17.10 and Code::Blocks 17.12. When I try to compile a simple "Hello World" program it gives me this error:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in test5 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------  
g++ -Wall -fexceptions -g -std=c++11  -c "/home/user/Documents/test5/main.cpp" -o obj/Debug/main.o
g++  -o bin/Debug/test5 obj/Debug/main.o
g++: error: obj/Debug/main.o: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Even in Code::Blocks 16.10 and 13.12 I kept getting the same error.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have all your code files in the current working directory, otherwise you'll have to include their path(s) in the compile command.

[This page](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Creating_a_new_project) at http://wiki.codeblocks.org (the official wiki for Code::Blocks) is a guide to many of the beginning features of the creation and modification of a Code::Blocks project. If this is your first experience with Code::Blocks, here is a good starting point.